# Save wifi networks and passwords to recover them after reinstall OS

Tags: linux, wifi-configuration, manjaro, pop-os

I want to change my linux distribution, how can I save all my known wifi networks and passwords so that I can restore them after installing a new OS.

I want to switch from PopOs with gnome to Manjaro with KDE

Answer (score 8):

The WiFi passwords of saved networks can be acquired by running this command:

```
sudo grep psk= /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*
```

This will show you the list of the WiFi networks and their passwords.

On gnome, you may find the password of any connection by:

- Open Settings
- Click on WiFi
- On the WiFi access point (AP) name click on the small gear icon
- In the Security tab click "Show password" to view the saved password.

Comment: You also need to select known networks from the vertical 3-dot or hamburger menu while at the WiFi settings in order to be able to see all save networks. Otherwise it'll only show the connected networks and other in range.